# Converting Types into other Types

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is to get this line of code to work in my main method:

```
Expression exp = new Add(new Value(3.2), new Multiply(new Value(4.1), 
                 new Value(7.1)));
```

Here's my code:

```
public interface Expression {

public int accept(EvaluationVisitor visitor);
}
```

My Operation Class

```
public class Operation implements Expression {

private Expression lhs;
private Expression rhs;


public Operation(Value lhs, Value rhs)
{
    this.lhs = lhs;
    this.rhs = rhs;
}


public Expression getLHS()
{
    return lhs;
}

public Expression getRHS()
{
    return rhs;
}



public int accept(EvaluationVisitor visitor) {

    return 0;
}



}
```

Value Class(represents a float value):

```
public class Value implements Expression {

private float number;

public Value(float number)
{

    this.number = number;

}


public String toString()
{
    return String.valueOf(number);
}

public float getValue()
{
    return number;  
}



public int accept(EvaluationVisitor visitor) {

    return 0;
}

}
```

My Add and Multiply methods:

```
public class Add extends Operation {

private Value lhs;
private Value rhs;

public Add(Value lhs, Value rhs)
{

    super(lhs,rhs);

}

public String toString()
{
    return String.valueOf(lhs.getValue() + rhs.getValue());
}


public Value add()
{
    return new Value(lhs.getValue() + rhs.getValue());
}

}




public class Multiply extends Operation{

private Value lhs;
private Value rhs;



public Multiply(Value lhs, Value rhs)
{
    super(lhs,rhs);
}


public String toString()
{
    return String.valueOf(lhs.getValue() + rhs.getValue());
}


public Value mul()
{
    return new Value(lhs.getValue() * rhs.getValue());
}
}
```

Here's the line of code again:

```
 Expression exp = new Add(new Value(3.2), new Multiply(new Value(4.1), 
                  new Value(7.1)));
```

In my line of code that I'm trying to get to work, I want to find a way that the Multiply object can be a value can be taken in as an argument. I know that I could just create the object and then place it there by calling my method that returns a Value object, but a constructor is supposed to set up an object so the state of the object is valid. Is there anyway I could get around this?

Comment: why do you use so many useless line breaks in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make full use of your interface so you can treat the values and operator expressions indiscriminately. Right now you aren't doing that, for example, `Operation` which takes two `Value`s as arguments but stores them as `Expression`s.

You also have a problem which is that your subclasses of `Operation` are declaring duplicate members named `lhs` and `rhs`. Perhaps you've already noticed that right now you'll get null pointer exceptions if you try to call methods on `Add` and `Multiply`.

Here is a slight redesign:

```
public interface Expression {
    public Value evaluate();
}

public class Value implements Expression {
    private final float floatValue;

    public Value(float floatValue) {
        this.floatValue = floatValue;
    }

    public float floatValue() {
        return floatValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Value evaluate() {
        return this;
    }
}

public abstract class BinaryOperator implements Expression {
    protected final Expression lhs, rhs;

    public BinaryOperator(Expression lhs, Expression rhs) {
        this.lhs = lhs;
        this.rhs = rhs;
    }
}

public class Add extends BinaryOperator {
    public Add(Expression lhs, Expression rhs) {
        super(lhs, rhs);
    }

    @Override
    public Value evaluate() {
        return new Value(
            lhs.evaluate().floatValue()
                +
            rhs.evaluate().floatValue()
        );
    }
}

public class Multiply extends BinaryOperator {
    public Multiply(Expression lhs, Expression rhs) {
        super(lhs, rhs);
    }

    @Override
    public Value evaluate() {
        return new Value(
            lhs.evaluate().floatValue()
                *
            rhs.evaluate().floatValue()
        );
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
Expression exp = (
    new Add(new Value(3.2f), new Multiply(new Value(4.1f), new Value(7.1f)))
);
System.out.println(exp.evaluate().floatValue());
```

Which outputs `32.309998` (the correct answer).

The above redesign could be further simplified if `evaluate` simply returned a `float`.

Comment: Is there a way that I can apply the visitor pattern to this? I like the design, but it completely rids of my visitor variables and methods( accept() ).

Comment: The visitor pattern is for run time decision making. I don't see how it applies here. Since your usage of it is just placeholder (no action taken and just returns 0) I don't know what to tell you. Not sure what you were trying to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

The constructors take `Value` objects but `Multiply` does not extend `Value`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is adding a value to an operation. What you really want to be doing is adding a value to a value (the latter being the result of an operation). So you should do the following:

```
Expression exp = new Add(new Value(3.2), new Multiply(new Value(4.1), 
             new Value(7.1)).mul());
```

Alternatively, you could make your `Operation` class extend `Value` and override the `getValue()` method inside the `Multiply` class to perform the multiplication and return the value (likewise in the `Add` class to perform the addition and return the value).